# How to access attribute within a list of dicts in python?

Tags: python

Assume I have a dict:

```
firstdict = {"somelist":[]}
```

I have another dict:

```
  seconddict = {"attribute1": "value1", "attribute2": "value2"}
```

After appending the dictionary

```
firstdict["somelist"].append(seconddict)
```

I want to print the "attribute1" value. Though the following statement is not working:

```
print firstdict["somelist"][0].attribute1
```

How to I print/access the value of attribute1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> firstdict = {"somelist":[]}
>>> seconddict = {"attribute1": "value1", "attribute2": "value2"}
>>> firstdict["somelist"].append(seconddict)
>>> print firstdict["somelist"][0]['attribute1']
value1
```

Answer (score 1):

it's     `firstdict["somelist"][0]['attribute1']`

Answer (score 1):

Python is not JavaScript; "attribute1" is no attribute, it is the key in the dictionary.  To access the corresponding value, you use the [] indexing operator, just like you did with firstdict:

```
subdict = firstdict["somelist"][0]
print subdict["attribute1"]
```

or, simply:

```
print firstdict["somelist"][0]["attribute1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firstdict["somelist"][0]['attribute1']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird to be storing dictionaries inside of a list inside of a dictionary. If you're using this to collect values from multiple dictionaries checkout [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression).

You might also consider nesting dictionaries:

```
>>>seconddict = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
>>>firstdict = {'dict 1': seconddict}
>>> firstdict['dict 1']['key1']
'value1'
```